# How do you hydrate unrelated tables with Doctrine createQuery?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

Could someone tell me what is wrong with this code snippet?

```
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $dql = <<<DQL
SELECT of, f, s
FROM MyBundle:OrgFeatures of
INNER JOIN of.feature f
INNER JOIN MyBundle:FeatureMasterLang s WITH s.featureMaster=f.id
WHERE of.orgPermissionset = :permissionsetId AND
s.lang = 1 AND
of.feature IN(:featureIds)
DQL;
        $query = $em->createQuery($dql)
            ->setParameter('permissionsetId', $permissionsetId)
            ->setParameter('featureIds', $featureIds);

        $resultSet = $query->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 141
            [privateCreate] => 1
            [publicView] => 1
            [feature] => Array
                (
                    [createdAt] => 
                    [modifiedAt] => 
                    [deletedAt] => 
                    [id] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [featureName] => Referrals
        )
    )
)
```

I need the array to be one element instead of two, with the `featureName` inside the `[feature]` array.  Is this possible?